# Strip / comic with a young child's teddy bear being ripped open for a CD

Tags: identification-request, comics

I can hardly remember any of it, but it has been bugging me for days that I cannot seem to identify this strip. I know one fact for sure.

The beginning of a volume started on a boat, in which 'invaders / evil guys' infiltrated the hut to search for a CD. On the deck, they question a father of a young child where it is, he then cannot help but look at his young child, and the villain smiles with 'of course' and rips open her teddy bear to steal the disk.

I'll try to remember more, but this is everything I know for sure now.